# How to change the app title in a UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, title, titlebar

I'm trying to change the app title dynamically in a Win 10 UWP app using the code below. The colors change but the title won't change. Any suggestions?

```
public AppShell()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var appTitle = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title;
    appTitle = house.Name;

    var appTitleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    appTitleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.LightBlue;
    appTitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.LightBlue;
    appTitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.Black;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
appView.Title = "Your title...";
```

Comment: That changes the title of the app's main window in the title bar, not the tile.

Comment: Great. That works perfectly. I guess my code didn't work because Title is not a static property. Thank you.

Comment: @BoltClock check my answer if you want to change the App Title instead of the View title (sorry, 2 years late...)

Answer (score 12):

Current accepted answer modifies the View title, not the App title. That appears to be good enough for the OP but if you want to actually change the App Title for a UWP app, here's what you do.

Open your package manifest and navigate to the "Application" tab. You'll see the app's display name like so,

[image: basic_name]

Then just change the **"Display name:"** field to whatever you want your custom app title to be, then re-build and you're good to go, like below,

[image]

Comment: This does not allow for dynamic changes.